# The equation representing the dissolution of cycasin

Tags: organic-chemistry, equilibrium, solubility, chemical-formula

Is the following equation correct? 
$$\ce{{C_8H_{16}N_2O_7}_{(s)} + H2O_{(l)} <=>  {C_8H_{16}N_2O_7}_{(aq)}}$$

Comment: Usually solubility is not represented by chemical equations. But most chemists will understand it and perhaps be okay with it.

Comment: Balanced equation: $$\ce{C8H16N2O7(s) <=>  C8H16N2O7(aq)}$$

Comment: [Water Solubility of cycasin](https://foodb.ca/compounds/FDB018287) is $\pu{56.6 g/L}$ (it is a glucoside). Thus, it is fair to use a forward arrow instead of equlibrium sign.

Comment: Yes but I want to say it is an application of solubitity equlibria, that when the cycasin solution is washed away, the equilibrium is shifted to the right, producing more cycasin solution.

Comment: @M.Farooq Solubility was taught partly in terms of chemical equations to me in highschool, college, and university. That doesn't give or take merit to the practice, but problem or not, it has been systemic in my experience.